# why cannot I get the value from the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

There is a dictionary called garden.fruit

```
garden.fruits = {"fruit" : "apple"}
```

And now I want to get the value of the key "fruit" from dictionary.
The code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding:utf-8 -*-
garden.fruits = {"fruit" : "apple"}
print garden.fruits['fruit']
```

But I get a name error

```
NameError: name 'garden' is not defined
```

I know the variation name should not include the **dot**, but what if I want use this variation name and get the value from the dictionary? Thanks

Comment: Python variables' namespaces don't allow `.` I'm pretty sure. Use an underscore instead. What happens when you do `print garden`?

Comment: Try this instead `fruits = {"fruit" : "apple"}`.  Dot's are not allowed that way.

Comment: Can you show us the full error message? I'm pretty sure it is raised when you are trying to do `garden.fruits = whatever`...

Comment: what is garden here? an class instance?

Comment: This problem clearly is not around *getting* a value from a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` would only be used if you had previously imported the file or package `garden` into the current namespace. For instance:

In `garden.py`:

```
fruits = {"fruit" : "apple"}
```

In `main.py`:

```
import garden
print garden.fruits['fruit']
```

However, if you are not importing the file or package `garden`, you cannot use `.`. Instead, declare fruits:

```
fruits = {"fruit" : "apple"}
print(fruits['fruit'])
```

Comment: That's not the only way, it could be class like `class garden: fruits = {"fruit" : "apple"}` (not advised of course)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)